# how to find out if a program sends data to internet (without permission)?

Tags: firewalls, sniffer, smtp

We have an application to save our customers data (some kind of CRM). This application has been written in Delphi and is a client/server application.  This program apparently is sending out information to Internet but we are not entirely sure. The person who wrote it is not reachable anymore.

On the data server we have not Internet connection and I think the clients parts maybe send information via email or some other way...

How to find out if this application sends data (maybe once a day !) ? What data and to which address it sends? This application is working on windows XP.

Comment: netbalancer is a decent tool to find out which applications are sending data to internet http://seriousbit.com/netbalancer/

Answer (score 3):

You can use [TCP View](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx) which is usually used by investigators and security experts to determine the behavior of certain malware, where it's establishing connections/getting commands from, or more common use is to solve cases where an individual is spying on another by use of Webcam/Microphone etc, by tracing the IP address; an example use of TCPView in such cases is that of [Jared James Abrahams](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2504411/Teenage-hacker-tried-sextort-Miss-Teen-USA-naked-pictures-got-logging-webcam-pleads-guilty.html) who [hacked](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2504411/Teenage-hacker-tried-sextort-Miss-Teen-USA-naked-pictures-got-logging-webcam-pleads-guilty.html) into several of his peer's computers to sextort them with pictures of he would take via their hacked webcam. (Sometimes the "hacker" is just someone without much knowledge in security/IT, so they don't take precautions to mask their IP)

[This is an example of TCP View showing an executable connecting to external addresses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKJ7Y.jpg)

Then to know what data the executables are sending, you can do packet sniffing, using software such as [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) that allows you to a network protocol analyzer.

Answer (score 1):

In case you have no privileges (or other possibilities) to install [TCP View](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx) you can always try a build-in Windows CLI command **[Netstat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netstat)**. It is not so convenient as TCP View, but nevertheless, it is able to provide information about protocol, source IP, destination IP and state of the current connections.